# How to connect to a VM created by VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualhost, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I have created a Fedora VM using VirtualBox and also have set the networking adapter to bridge mode. Inside Fedora I've set the ip to be 192.168.1.14.
Now if I issue a ping from my Host machine (Win 7) to this VM it successfully responds.
The problem is I have installed the [Red5](http://wiki.red5.org/wiki/Install) server on this VM of mine but I can not access it outside the VM itself (it's only accessible from inside on port 5080)!
I wonder what is the problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Fedora's firewall turned on?  Do you have an outgoing filter on your Win7 machine?  Is Red5 listening on eth0 (and not just the loopback interface)?  If the VM is using bridged mode for networking, for all intents and purposes, it will look like another box on the network, and any network issues you have will tend to be the usual ones.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was the firewall which was preventing the connection.